# Broken pipe when using pipe and dup2 to redirect stdin/stdout

Tags: c, unix

I want to reproduce what would happen when typing in a shell:

```
ps eaux | grep "^USERNAME" | wc -l
```

*(Where `USERNAME` is either the `$USER` env var or whatever was provided as an argument to my program.)*

Unfortunately this doesn't work :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    int pipefd1[2];
    int pipefd2[2];
    pipe(pipefd1);
    pipe(pipefd2);



    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {


        switch (fork()) {
            case -1:
                perror("Fork error");
            case 0:
                pipe(pipefd2);
                if (i == 0) { // Execution of grep

                    char grepArg[1024];

                    if (argc == 2) {
                        sprintf(grepArg, "\"^%s\"", argv[1]);
                    } else {
                        sprintf(grepArg, "\"^%s\"", getenv("USER"));
                    }

                    close(pipefd1[1]);
                    close(pipefd2[0]);

                    dup2(pipefd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                    dup2(pipefd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

                    close(pipefd1[0]);
                    close(pipefd2[1]);

                    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);

                } else { // Execution of wc
                    close(pipefd1[0]);
                    close(pipefd1[1]);
                    close(pipefd2[1]);

                    dup2(pipefd2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(pipefd2[0]);
                    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
                }

        }

    }
    close(pipefd1[0]);
    dup2(pipefd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefd1[1]);
    execlp("ps", "ps", "eaux", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
       0
cat: stdout: Broken pipe
```

What's wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: The child creates a brand new pipe (pipefd2) but closes the read end without forking a child to manage that read end. So the write to it fails as the pipe is broken.

Comment: @TJohnson Thank you !I had indeed forgot to call fork on pipefd2, but isn't this correct to call it from the parent as I am doing ?

Comment: @TJohnson Edited my question with correct call to pipe

Comment: You need a lot of work in case 0 (the child). Keep in mind that both the read and write end of the pipe must be open. Typically you will create a pipe and then fork so the parent can use one end while the child uses the other end. In your child there seems to be no need to open another pipe. Then be careful to ensure that some process is writing and some other process is reading from the pipe.